# Django Rest Framework Test case issue: 'HttpResponseNotAllowed' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

My tests file code:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class CategoryTests(APITestCase):

  def test_create_create(self):

    url = '/category/add/'
    data = {"name":"Sports","description":"get live updates here"}
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.data, data)
```

Error which I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/test/webapp/apps/core/tests.py", line 16, in test_create_create
self.assertEqual(response.data, data)
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseNotAllowed' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Infact the tests are not even calling the exact api statements(I checked that using debug statements in api code). Please let me know what may be going wrong or you need any more information on this.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the DRF extended test client:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient

class CategoryTests(APITestCase):
  client = APIClient()

  def test_create_create(self):

    url = '/category/add/'
    data = {"name":"Sports","description":"get live updates here"}
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEquals(response.data, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with url, I correct it and it worked. So my url was actually

```
url = '/v1.0/category/add/'
```